# set text string in template link button "eval"

Tags: asp.net, eval, settext

I need to set the Text in a gridview column to something other than what shows up in gridview with this code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCustomer" runat="server" 
     OnClick="lnkCustomer_Click" Text='<%# Eval("ImgLnk") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

Of course what shows up is the contents of "ImgLnk" in string form which is a hyper link ie "http://...." I would rather it say "Picture" in gridview.

Comment: This is not really javascript, but more asp.net. Do you want all lines in your grid to just say Picture?

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCustomer" runat="server" Text='Picture'
     CommandName="CustomerLink" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ImgLnk") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

Then in your click/command event handler:

```
if (e.CommandName == "CustomerLink")
{
    Response.Redirect(e.CommandArgument);
}
```

Comment: I absolutely like this answer. I see how it can work.  I think I must have my event handler set up incorrectly. It begins  protected void lnkCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) and I get an eventargs error relating to CommandName and CommandArgument. Can you please guide me to the correction? ...and no I don't wish to have all lines say Picture.  Just the ones where db field != null.  Thanks so much. Big help here!

Comment: this answer does not work...I had such high hopes...thanks for trying Curt!

Comment: @user1589714 If your `LinkButton` is nested in a gridview you don't need an onclick event, just use the RowCommand event for the gridview. That's why you were receiving an error

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Curt. I am in so far over my head... I have no idea what you are talking about.  I will keep coming back as I learn to see if know later...haha.

Comment: @user1589714 Haha we all have to learn at some point. This documentation might be of some help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx